# how can I iterate over another table in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-admin

How to iterate over another table in react-admin with ability to change values.

My code now looks like this:

```
const WorkshopEdit = props => {
    console.log(props);

    return (<Edit {...props} undoable={false}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <ArrayInput source="placeTimes">
                <SimpleFormIterator>
                    <TextInput source="place" />
                    <DateTimeInput source="startTime" />
                    <DateTimeInput source="endTime" />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>
            <DisabledInput source="id" />
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <LongTextInput source="description" />
            <NumberInput source="capacity" label="Вместимость" />
            <NumberInput source="order" />
            <TextInput source="image" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>);
};
```

Values is showing, but i not able to edit this. I tried to use ReferenceInput, ReferenceArrayInput, but no clue. 
`Workshop` and `placeTimes` two diffrent entities

Comment: you mean you are trying to change record and its not working?

Comment: if you not having on change you can't edit this . i think so.

Comment: ye, it's not working. it works without onChange even, cause `react-admin`